# How to I pass props in AppRegistry registerComponent react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

thanks in advance

How do I pass props from my index js using AppRegistry

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName,  () => App);
```

I also need to pass props too AppSide, prop which is from the index.

And my App looks like this

```
export default () => (
  <Provider store={store} >
    <AppSide />
  </Provider >
);
```

I also need to pass the props to **AppSide**

Any Solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your main app component in another component and add any extra props you need there

in your index.js:

```
const AppWrapper = (props) => {
  return <App {...{
    ...props,
    extra: "extraprop",
  }}/>;
};

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => AppWrapper);
```

Comment: Make sure to import `react` and rename `index.js` to `index.jsx`